# Print @NotBlank message only if a field is Not Empty

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I built a form validation system using Spring mvc.
This is my object User

```
public class User{

    @NotEmpty   
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=3,max=20)
    private String name;    
.....
}
```

So far, if you don't fill the "name" field you get 3 messages:

1. may not be empty
2. may not be blank
3. size must be between 3 and 20

Is there a way, for example, to get the message 2 just if the message 1 is not sent?

I explain better: if a user doesn't fill a field I just want to print the message "may not be empty". Then, if the user fills a field with just spaces I want to print the message "may not be blank".
Then, if the field is filled (then is not empty) and doesn't contain just spaces (then is not blank) I want to print the size message.

Is there a way to handle this issue with annotation or I have to create my own validator class?

I looked into it on the internet but I didn't find a solution, probably because it's difficult to explain Google what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group` and `@GroupSequence` to achive order with your validator:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own annotation and use the meta constraint @ReportAsSingleViolation.

have a look at these websites

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html

So your code could look

```
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@NotEmpty   
@NotBlank
@Length(min = 3, max = 20)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {

    public abstract String message() default "{customkey}";

    public abstract Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public abstract Class<?>[] payload() default {};
}
```